# Problema no python pyAudio

Tags: python

Estou criando um assistente virtual em Python, pro projeto da escola, não manjo muito de Python, e sempre da erro no pyAudio, onde eu já procurei como resolver e nada encontrei, o erro são esses :

- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio
- AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

```py
import speech_recognition as sr #Biblioteca para rec. de voz (transcreve fala em texto)
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot
import comtypes.client as ct

tts = ct.CreateObject("sapi.SPVoice")
r = sr.Recognizer()

bot = ChatBot('Bot')
dialogo = ['Oi','Olá','olá','oi','tudo bem?','estou bem, e você?','estou bem','que bom'] #Lista de dialogos para treinar o bot
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
bot.train(dialogo)

def main():
  try:
    while True:
      with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) # Ajustando ruído ambiente
        audio = r.listen(source) # Extrai áudio do microfone
        speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-BR') #transcrevendo fala em texto com api da Google
        print('Você: ', speech)
        response = bot.get_response(speech)
        print('Bot: ', response)
        resposta = (u""+str(response))
        tts.Speak(resposta)
  except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print('Erro de reconhecimento de fala')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Você não possui a instalação do pyAudio onde está executando o código, ou instalou o pacote numa versão diferente.

Comment: e então como eu instalo? o pip install pyaudio da erro(lembrando que eu tenho o pip)

Comment: Para instalar siga a [Documentação do Pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/); O erro que você tem é que o pyaudio não está instalado

Comment: Instale PyAudio áudio. Você pode fazer a instalação usando o comando:
pip install PyAudio

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente quando ele da um erro que não achou o módulo significa que você não instalou ele, para instalar o módulo [pyAudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/) você deve digitar isso no seu CMD ou Terminal se for no linux:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

---

- [Módulos Python](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/modules.html)